# Cannot enlarge a LUKS filesystem

Tags: linux, partitioning, filesystems, disk-space, luks

I enlarged a LUKS partition from 2.7TB to 3.7TB with GParted. `lsblk` and `fdisk -l` now show the desired size, but `df -h` still shows 2.7TB, and I can only write as much to the disk. `resize2fs` and `e2fsck` didn't help.

Here is selected output from `lsblk`, `fdisk` and `df`.

```
$ lsblk
sda                                     8:0    0   3.7T  0 disk
└─sda2                                  8:2    0   3.7T  0 part
  └─luks-006fb82a-e5ad-46a7-944c-3b3ccb2bb23e
                                      253:3    0   3.7T  0 crypt /mnt/data


# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/sda: 3.65 TiB, 4000787030016 bytes, 7814037168 sectors
Disk model: ST4000DM000-1F21
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A2153689-78CA-4630-8E8B-980041E2BC44

Device     Start        End    Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda2   2048 7814033407 7814031360  3.7T Linux filesystem

Disk /dev/mapper/luks-006fb82a-e5ad-46a7-944c-3b3ccb2bb23e: 3.65 TiB, 4000779862016 bytes, 7814023168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes


$ df -h
/dev/dm-3                   2.7T  1.6T  1.1T  60% /mnt/data
```

Is there anything I can do except reformatting the HDD entirely?

Comment: resize the "container" with `cryptsetup` after resizing the partition and before resizing the filesystem: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/cryptsetup.8.html

Comment: @Tom, it worked, thanks! Would you make it an answer, so that I can accept it?